# XHTML namespaces and CSS attribute selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, xhtml, xml-namespaces

I can't figure out how to get CSS attribute selectors to style elements based on namespaced attributes without resorting to the ordinary HTML name of the namespaced attribute (including the colon).

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="https://stackoverflow.com/foo">
 <head>
  <title>CSS Attribute Selectors with namespaces</title>
  <style>
   @namespace foo "http://www.stackoverflow.com/foo";
   span[foo|id=bar] { font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span foo:id="bar">Should be monospace bold</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

Test case:

I opened the file in both Chrome and Firefox by typing the appropriate file:/// URL into my address bar; in neither case does it show up correctly. It also does not show up correctly on Stack Overflow.

If I change the snippet to include the HTML attribute name:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:foo="https://stackoverflow.com/foo">
 <head>
  <title>CSS Attribute Selectors with namespaces</title>
  <style>
   @namespace foo "http://www.stackoverflow.com/foo";
   span[foo\:id=bar] { font-family: monospace; font-weight: bold; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <span foo:id="bar">Should be monospace bold</span>
 </body>
</html>
```

... it works correctly (both using my local browser and on the Stack Overflow snippet).

I've read the set of gotchas included in [Can you style XHTML elements in another namespace using id and class name css selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151615/can-you-style-xhtml-elements-in-another-namespace-using-id-and-class-name-css-se) and [Do CSS namespace attribute selectors work with XHTML/HTML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628932/do-css-namespace-attribute-selectors-work-with-xhtml-html-elements) but I have not yet been able to figure this out; I believe I've done everything both questions' answers suggest.

Removing the DOCTYPE didn't do it, although I suspect some kind of DOCTYPE problem given that the HTML form works and the XHTML form does not.

I must be missing something simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your document needs to be processed as an XHTML document for the XML namespaces to work. Note that having an XHTML DOCTYPE *and* the relevant `xmlns` attributes is not enough.

You do this on the server side by serving the document as Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml, or on the file system by saving the document with a .xhtml file extension instead of .html. For a very quick and dirty test case you can even copy your entire markup, drop it in the address bar, prepend `data:application/xhtml+xml,`, and navigate to the resulting data URI.

This is mentioned in very brief passing by the first question you link to:

> If I switched the mime-type to application/xhtml+xml

Note also that the namespace in your CSS must *exactly* match the namespace in the markup. `@namespace foo "http://www.stackoverflow.com/foo";` does not match `xmlns:foo="http://stackoverflow.com/foo"` because of the `www.`. (Interestingly, the `foo` identifiers do not need to match, because unlike the namespaces themselves the identifiers are separate.)

Comment: excellent, I'll fix the typo in the namespaces (obviously my quick-n-dirty copy-paste-modify from my real project introduced a regression), and then I'll try the rest on my browser.

Comment: Renaming the file to .xhtml does it. I also tried a meta http-equiv to set the content type (without renaming the file); that did *not* do it.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell That's right, the content-type in the `<meta http-equiv` command can't change the file type, only the charset. (And the latter only if the charset was not specified in the actual http header or the xml declaration.)

Comment: I know this is a bit old question, but I'm experiencing same problems. I'm trying to use namespaces in attribute selectors in HTML5, not XHTML - how do I do it? Everything is correct, namespace link too.

Comment: What's weird, w3c validator shows me parse errors when using the `|`